# Google map not loading Android

Tags: android, google-maps

Though I know this has been a persistent and addressed issue, everyone's problem seems to be solved a different way every time. I have been trying to get my map to show all day but to no avail. I had a project which had a map in it, so what I migrated that project to another location and set up Google Play Services in that project. I got everything to work except for the map to show. I have the library as i am able to use `LatLng` but the map always fails to load. I have generated new keys, deleted and re added the key, and deleted and re added the debug keystore. I have also updated the api console to ensure everything lined up but my map still doesnt show. I have Google Map for Android Api enabled in the console. And my package name is correct also. I have ran a clean rebuild and uninstalled the app to see if it works but it still doesnt load. 
NOTE: I have also tried using `SupportMapFragment` instead.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.android.wallfly"
android:largeHeap="true">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Actionbarstyle">

    <activity
        android:name="com.android.wallfly.MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="(Actual API Key)" />

</application>

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<permission
    android:name="com.android.wallfly.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.wallfly.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<!-- these grant the app the ability to access location. coarse is wifi and cellular, fine is gps -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I have added an image to show that my package name lines up. Also i copied and pasted the SHA1 fingerprint so I am sure that it does line up also.[image]

Comment: are you able to see the google logo and the grid lines in the map???

Comment: @Lal I am able to see the Google logo, no gridlines however. No other errors except that it failed to contact google servers.

Comment: usually if the error is 'error contacting google servers' then it is because of the wrong API key..

Comment: check if you have more than one key for the project in the API console..

Comment: @Lal I have copied and pasted every api key i have generated right into the manifest, uninstalled the app, did a clean rebuild, and reinstalled the app.

Comment: Also check if you have generated the Android Key...

Comment: did you notice the status that is in your posted image?? It says it is active only till Aug 5 2014 10:34 AM

Comment: Perhaps you are clicking the "Generate new key" link to the right of your existing key. That is for replacing an existing key, and the original key will be removed after 24 hours.

Instead, click "Create new Android key..." at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Lal yes, It was because I had recently generated a new key, the status is for the old key, I immediately switch keys once I generate a new one. The API key that is generated is not the android key?

Comment: You please try after generating a new android key...It might work...

Comment: The problem you describing usually derives from a problem in generating or registering the API key using the API Console, If you are positive that you have made all the steps correctly then I suggest you to delete the **debug.keystore** folder, compile some project in Eclipse (this will result in a new SHA1 key) and register the key again using the console.

Comment: @Lal I just created a new android key. Still getting the error.

Comment: Please don't forget to clear program cache before trying new API KEY as Android will use first API key even if you change API key.

Comment: @Lal I cleared the caches but still doesnt work. If you have anymore suggestions, perhaps we should move the conversation to chat.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may face a similar problem, my google play service was outdated. So I had to change the `build.gradle` the  current version of google play service.